# How do you make GUI buttons that lead to different pages in the directory with Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm making a program for my mother to repay here for all she did with me. I am trying to make a program similar to Cash Register Express. How would I make a GUI similar to it and linking to other pages? And if it doesn't work with Java, any other programming languages?

Comment: Some portions of your question are specific -- for example, how to "link to other pages", and this has been answered by MadProgrammer below, but the rest of your question is much too broad and vague to answer. Better for you to delve in, to try to create your GUI, and then if you run into specific stumbling blocks, come on back with specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and you will want to pay close attention to [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 1):

CardLayout used in Swings will be a good option. All the best for your work !